# Prove that there only two groups of order 4 up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Can the following statement be proved?

> There are only two different groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism.

I have seen somewhere that there are only two groups up to isomorphism of order $4$ -cyclic of order $4$ and the Klein-$4$ group.

All other groups with $4$ elements are isomorphic to one of these.

Really I don't have any idea on attempting this problem, so I please need your help.

Thanks all!

Comment: Recall that the order of an element always divides the size of the group. Only one element can have order $1$ (the identity). What options are left?

Answer (score 19):

HINT:

1. What happens if the group has an element of order $4$?
2. If it has no such element, the three non-identity elements all have order ... what? Then give them names $-$ $a,b$, and $c$, for instance $-$ and start filling out the group multiplication table. You’ll find that there’s only one way to do so that’s consistent with the properties required of a group.

Comment: Just wondering, for (2), is there a more effective ways of knowing the number of elements of each order, here order 1 and 2, other than filling in the multiplication table. Because if the order of the group is bigger, filling in multiplication table is not feasible

Comment: @user136266: In general that’s not an easy question, but neither is the question of how many non-isomorphic groups there are of a given order.

Comment: I don’t suppose that the downvoter would care to be useful and explain what’s wrong? No, I didn’t think so.