# What does it mean: "As a group of order four, what type of subgroup is $H$, a $V_4$ or a $\Bbb Z_4$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading lecture notes and found this exercise but have trouble understanding what I am supposed to do.

As a group of order four, what type of subgroup is $H$, a $V_4$ or a $\Bbb Z_4$?

I would appreciate if you give additional explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your lecture notes: is $H$ a group or a subgroup of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There are two groups of order four up to isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100948/104041):

- The Klein four group, denoted $V_4$.
- The cyclic group $\Bbb Z_4$.

The question asks you to identify which one $H$ is isomorphic to.

Comment: If the condition of H is only "a group of order four", it can be V4 and Z4 either of them. correct? Because it does not give any additional information regarding H.

Comment: Yes, it can be either, @momo. All groups of order four are isomorphic to either $V_4$ or $\Bbb Z_4$ (but not both).

Comment: It could be, though, for example, @momo, that $H$ is a subgroup of a cyclic group; all subgroups of cyclic groups are themselves cyclic, so in that case $H\cong \Bbb Z_4$.